# How does associate in Laravel/Eloquent work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get associate to work.

Relationship on User model:

```
public function group()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

So I do:

```
$user = new User();
//save user fields
....
$user->save();

$group = Group::find(1);
$user->group()->associate($group);
```

A new user is inserted, but in the FK of group_id on the user table I am getting null.

Comment: No error, I do have the namespace in my code for the relationship, deleted for ease of reading.

Answer (score 1):

Associate needs to be before save.

```
$user = new User();
//save user fields
....
$group = Group::find(1);
$user->group()->associate($group);
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let say you want to associate a comment with a blog post, because the comment can only be for a specific post we will use associate.
In our Post model we will have this:

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

in our comment model we have this:

```
         public function post(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
```

In our CommentsController we will have this:

```
  $comment = new Comment;
  $post=Post::find($post_id);
  $comment->post()->associate($post);
  $comment->save();
```

Pay attention that you save it only after you associate it with the post.

Answer (score 0):

you need to save user after associating

```
$user->save();
```

full code

```
$user = User::create([
   'field1' => $request->field1,
....
]);

$group = Group::find(1);
$user->group()->associate($group);
$user->save();
```